# Hide Dropdown list on 'EDIT' button & show on 'ADD' Button click

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am using a similar page for **edit** and **add** functionality in MVC(C#).Now I want to hide Drop down on **EDIT** but not on **ADD**.
help to find the solution .Thanks in advance

Below is a part of my View

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label>SamsatName</label><br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.SamsatId, Model.SamsatNamelist, "Choose one Samsat...", new { @id = "SamsatId" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.SamsatId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Comment: How do you distinguish between EDIT and ADD in your page?

Comment: Using **UserId** ,at the time of edit I passed the encoded **UserID**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming** that your Model class has an `Id`, which is an `int` and is populated when you are on edit mode and it is 0 -default value for `int`- when you are on a add mode, you could try this:

```
@if(Model.Id == 0)
{
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>SamsatName</label><br />
         @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.SamsatId, Model.SamsatNamelist, "Choose one Samsat...", new { @id = "SamsatId" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.SamsatId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
}
```

If the property that distinguishes models one another is not called `Id` or it is not an `int`, you should change the above `if` condition correspondingly.